# JQuery detect if a tag is self closing

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to detect if a tag is self closing with JQuery like an image tag?  Something dynamic not just an image tag.

```
if ($('.selector')[0].tagName.toLowerCase()=="img") {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to find this out?

Comment: @cletus: Stems from the OP's previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291434/jquery-check-if-prepend-failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need to distinguish between an element that's empty vs self-closing? If not, you can use:

```
if ($(".selector").is(":empty")) {
  // do something
}
```

But if you're talking about detecting whether a given HTML tag should be empty or not, no you can't do that programmatically because you're not stopped from creating invalid HTML and you need to validate it against a DTD to find out.

Comment: This works for my purposes and so does the above, but I think this one is the cleanest answer.

Answer (score 14):

jQuery uses this list internally:

```
/^(?:area|br|col|embed|hr|img|input|link|meta|param)$/i
```

You can do the same:

```
if(/^(?:area|br|col|embed|hr|img|input|link|meta|param)$/i.test($('.selector')[0].tagName)) {
//do something
}
```

Comment: Solid answer, but <wbr> tag is missing from this list. (Perhaps it was added within the last 8 years though :P)

Comment: Also realized: missing <input>. Which is a much bigger deal.
If you have inline SVGs that this code could touch, you'll also have <path> tags among others. Edge case, but worth mentioning.

Comment: - For a list of self closing tag: [HTML5 spec] https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#void-elements ; 
- Also, custom tags cannot be self closing tags > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23961178/do-custom-elements-require-a-close-tag

Answer (score 4):

You need a little background. The HTML markup that's sent across the wire is parsed by the browser into a DOM tree. At the point, the original markup is gone, served it's purpose, and no longer exists. When you do `innerHTML` on an element, that's not the literal HTML that generated the element, but the browser's serialization of that DOM subtree.

The point is, there is no different between `<div />` and `<div></div>`. So just see if it has any children. If it doesn't, the element *does* have a possible XHTML representation that uses a self-closing tag.

```
element.children().length == 0
```

or as cletus says:

```
element.is(":empty")
```

Comment: `children()` does not return text nodes. As jQuery implements it, you should use `element.contents().length` instead of `element.children().length`. Children() returns all children _tag_ elements. Contents() returns all children _tag_ elements **plus** all node_text. Example:  `$('<div>hello</div>').children().length` returns 0, while `$('<div>hello</div>').contents().length` returns 1.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the `.html()` accessor to see if it returns an empty string. Though this will return true on `<p></p>` but I'd imaging for all intents and purposes that could be treated as a self closing tag.