# Do custom elements require a close tag?

Tags: html, polymer

Elements I've defined (that don't require contents) seem to work just fine without a closing tag. I'm wondering if it's just a quirk of the browser though.

What's the verdict? Is it theoretically possible? What if the parser sees the element before its definition?

Comment: Can you give an example of the element? And details of the browser you're using if you think it's relevant?

Comment: Regarding that "theoretically": empty elements with a self-closing open tag (like `<P />`) should definitely be possible. In practice, though, from what I've read (e.g. on SO), browsers have mostly just been ignoring self-closing open tags, unfortunately.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/624.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes. Custom elements require a closing tag. Only certain tags in HTML are allowed to be self-closing due to the parser.

> The following is a complete list of the void elements in HTML:
>
> area, base, br, col, command, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, meta, param, source, track, wbr

and :

> A non-void element must have an end tag, unless the subsection for that element in the HTML elements section of this reference indicates that its end tag can be omitted.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements

Comment: Expanding on this, when I've left off closing tags the parser has inserted them fairly late. So `<x-foo> <x-bar> <x-baz>` was interpreted as `<x-foo> <x-bar> <x-baz> </x-baz> </x-bar> </x-foo>` which can lead to some unexpected results.

Comment: I found this to block `document.querySelector`...any elements after the self-closing web-component element aren't selectable.

Comment: To clarify, my understanding is that if you write `<my-component />`, the HTML5 parser will simply ignore the `/`! Ignoring the `/` is fine in the case of void elements like `<br />` (which simply becomes `<br>`), but for web components, it means that the following elements get gobbled up *into* the web component, as @PeterBurns's example shows. So you need a full closing tag: `<my-component></my-component>`

As Remy Sharp [points out](https://remysharp.com/2023/10/09/why-i-stopped-loving-slashes-in-self-closing-tags), it's worth noting that JSX does use closing `/`, but HTML5 is different.