# Aurelia: self-closing require element does not work

Tags: html, aurelia

Why can't Aurelia deal with self-closing `require` elements?

For example:

`<require from="component"></require>` works

`<require from="component"/>` doesn't work

No error is given, yet the entire template will fail if you try to use the self-closing element.

Comment: ahh I suspect its because its not valid html5 syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5

Comment: Yeah, custom elements are required to have a closing tag

Comment: I'll leave this here; I suspect other people will make the same mistake as I did.

Comment: I left an answer so the question can be marked answered

Comment: You tagged your question both html and xml. Which one is it? A document cannot be both.

Comment: html; made the mistake of thinking the templates were xml. Removed Tag.

Comment: Also related more closely http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23961178/do-custom-elements-require-a-close-tag

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the HTML specification, there are just a few [*void elements*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements) (elements that only have a start tag), which are:

> `area`, `base`, `br`, `col`, `embed`, `hr`, `img`, `input`, `keygen`, `link`, `meta`, `param`, `source`, `track`, `wbr`.
>
> https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements.

Aurelia uses the browser's native DOMParser, which means it follows the same set of standards.

Comment: this is kinda of weird... but I've noticed I'm doing self-closed `div`'s in the index.html (loaded directly by chrome) and its got no issues with it.