# Vue sfc spec is not compatible with html5 or xhtml or any xml format

Tags: parsing, templates, vue.js, standards, sfc

not compatible with html5 for vue allows 
`<my-component/>`
not compatible with xhtml or xml for vue allows empty attribute and tag without close mark like
`<my-component my-directive>`

Any one knows how to transform vue template to valid html5 format or any xml format? Any nodejs lib could handle it? (cheerio, jsdom, parse5, all of them follow current standard)

Comment: You need to parse Vue template tag? Before it is compiled and mounted by Vue framework? Or after it is compiled?

Comment: PS: Custom elements, like <my-components />, are valid in html5

Comment: yes, I want to parse vue template before vue-loader in a way like handling dom.

Comment: ` <my-components />` is invalid, you have to write it as `<my-components></my-components>` , you can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23961178/do-custom-elements-require-a-close-tag