# web component - accept no child elements

Tags: html, dom, web-component

How can I define a web component that works like `<img>` in that it accepts no child elements?

```html
  <script>
    const QA = (q, d) => Array.prototype.slice.call((d||document).querySelectorAll(q), 0);
    const QS = (q, d) => (d||document).querySelector(q);
  </script>

  <template id="push-message">
    <style>
      message { display: grid; font-family: sans-serif; background: #eee; outline: 1px solid; }
      .badge {  }
    </style> 
    <message>
      <img class="badge">
      <img class="icon">
      <img class="image">
    </message>
  </template>

  <script>    
    const wpm = 'push-message';
    customElements.define(wpm,
      class extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() { 
          super();
          const l = QS(`#${wpm}`).content.cloneNode(true);
          const s = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' }); s.appendChild(l);
        }
        QS(q) { return QS(q, this.shadowRoot); }
        QA(q) { return QA(q, this.shadowRoot); }  
        static get observedAttributes() { return [ "badge", "icon", "image" ]; }
        attributeChangedCallback(a, o, n) {
          if (/^(badge|icon|image)$/.test(a))
            this.QS(`.${a}`).src = n;
        }
      });
  </script>

  <push-message 
     badge="//google.com/favicon.ico"
      icon="//google.com/favicon.ico"
     image="//google.com/favicon.ico">
  <p>ok</p>
```

`DOM` should be

```
<push-message></push-message>
<p></p>
```

not

```
<push-message><p></p></push-message>
```

and `ok` should display in the result.

---

Is there a way to change `customElements.define` to avoid having to explicitly close `<push-message></push-message>` and just use `<push-message>` but have it implicitly self-close?

Comment: While you can't do it now it sure would be a nice upgrade. And, it _shouldn't_ really be that hard to implement. Just add an option when calling `define`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autonomous Custom Elements require a closing tag: [Do custom elements require a close tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23961178/do-custom-elements-require-a-close-tag)

You can create a Customized Built-In Element extended from HTMLImageElement
to get a a self-closing IMG tag:

```
<img is="push-message" badge="//google.com/favicon.ico">
<img is="push-message" icon="//google.com/favicon.ico">
<img is="push-message" image="//google.com/favicon.ico">
<p>ok</p>
```

But an IMG can only have one src, so you might as well create 3 elements and use

```html
<img is="message-badge">
<img is="message-icon">
<img is="message-image">
```

Answer (score 2):

Self-closing tags as known as [void elements](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#void-elements).

AFAIK, **it is not possible to create custom void elements**. In summary, it needs changing browser HTML parsers which is not an easy thing to pull by the web community. Changes are required because of the way the browser implements a [tag-soup algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup).

**Thus you will need a closing tag.** You can read more about this here:

- [Specs discussion](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/624)
- [Lit-html discussion](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-html/issues/630)

On a side note, if you have your own template compiler/parser like `vue-compiler` and `ng-compiler`, you can probably instruct it to understand self-closing custom elements at a build time. However, the benefits of achieving this are virtually non-existent.