# In Stencil with Jest, how to test object property on components using template?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, jsx, stenciljs

I have a stencil component that looks something like this:

```js
    export class MyBadge {
      @Prop() skin: string = 'primary';
      render(){
        return (
        <span class={`skin-${this.skin}`} />
      )
```

I want to write a unit test that checks that the rendered component applies the given `skin` property.
I have a test that compares the rendered component to my expected html, using `expect(page.root).toEqualHtml(´< span class=primary >´).` This test works! However, when I try to modify the prop, using template, it fails to run the test.

```js
    import { newSpecPage } from '@stencil/core/testing';
    import { MyBadge } from './my-badge'
    it('should have "secondary" skin', async () => {
     const page = newSpecPage({
            components: [MyBadge],
            template: () => (`
              <my-badge skin=secondary></my-badge>
              `), 
          });
          expect(page.root).toEqualHtml(`
          <span class="skin-secondary">
          ...
          `);
        });
```

This gives the error `expect toEqualHtml() value is "null"` and the test fails

I have also tried including the bellow html under the `it`, but that fails too.

```
html: `<my-badge></my-badge>`,
```

Removing the template option makes the test work, however it then does not see the updated prop.

I wanted to use the template option based on this answer:
https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/1923

I've also tried a few different syntaxes, I'm not clear on how to wrap the template string.

I've been looking around for documentation on this but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit:** Cleaned up the code based on suggestions from @Simon Hänisch

Comment: I realized that in my case, setting the property directly like this works:
`html: '<badge skin="secondary"></badge>'`
 However I'm still unclear on how to use template to set properties, and how best to test that the component gets the given properties.

Comment: The key concept I had not understood before Simon's answer was that the spec file should be tsx, which would the allow it to work with template, as you describe. Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your template is returning a string, not JSX. You basically get a document with `<badge skin=secondary></badge>` as a string in it, not an actual `badge` element.

BTW `badge` is not a valid custom element name, it needs to have a dash (`-`) in its name. There are also syntax errors in your example code, like your component should

```js
return (
  <span class={`skin-${this.skin}`} />
)
```

(back ticks for the class string were missing and the tag wasn't closed)

Assuming that all this is just mistakes when writing this question and you actually have a line with `newSpecPage` in your code (that's also missing here), here's what you need to do:

1. Change the extension of your spec test file to `.tsx`.
2. Add `import { h } from '@stencil/core';`.
3. Write some actual JSX as the return value of your template.

```js
import { h } from '@stencil/core';
import { newSpecPage } from '@stencil/core/testing';
import { MyBadge } from './my-badge';

it('should have "secondary" skin', async () => {
  const page = newSpecPage({
    components: [MyBadge],
    template: () => <my-badge skin="secondary" />,
  });

  expect(page.root).toEqualHtml('<span class="skin-secondary"></span>');
});
```

You can't use both options `template` and `html` at the same time (or at least it doesn't make sense, I'm not sure which one will take precedence), because they are different ways of setting the content for the page. If you use `template`, you can directly use JSX syntax to bind any kind of value to props etc. If you use `html`, it has to be a string with the html content of your page, and in that case you can only bind string values to props.

If you wanted to use `html` in your example instead, it would need to be

```js
const page = newSpecPage({
  components: [MyBadge],
  html: `<my-badge skin="secondary"></my-badge>`,
});
```

I don't think you can use the self-closing syntax in this case because it's not valid for custom elements, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23962294/2897426).

Comment: Thank you Simon, for this very well written and thoughtful answer. I will improve my question syntax based on your feedback, and try again with the template in the code.

Comment: I really should have read this more conscientiously: !!! 1. Change the extension of your spec test file to .tsx. !!! 
This almost drove me crazy for an hour or two. Thanks!!