# How to programmatically tell if a element is a self closing tag

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript and according to the HTML standard, how do I accomplish this? don't know where to start coding a function where `isSingleClosing('input')` must return true (note the `/>`) while `isSingleClosing('div')` returns false for example. self or single closing tag looks like this `<tag/>` and non single closing `<tag></tag>`

Comment: Do you already have some code? where are you stuck?

Comment: make an array of tags that are self closing. when the function is called, loop through the array and see if the passed value is in the array. If it is, return true. If it is not, return false.

Comment: Not really. This answer to a similar question notes the self-closing tag list that jQuery uses internally: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2292440/1324

Answer (score 6):

The most consistent and easiest would be to keep a list of self-closing elements

```
var elems = ['area', 'base', 'br', 'col', 'command', 'embed', 'hr', 'img', 'input', 'keygen', 'link', 'meta', 'param', 'source', 'track', 'wbr'];

function isSingleClosing(elem) {
    return elems.indexOf( elem.tagName.toLowerCase() ) !== -1;
}
```

Comment: Note that the crux here is that in HTML5 there _is no concept of self closing tags_ with `/>`. Doing `<input ... >` and `<input .../>` does exactly the same thing, the latter is only _allowed_ because people got used to writing this way.

Comment: Just want to point out that it looks like OP intends the function to receive a string representing the tag name, not an actual element

Comment: @CrayonViolent - well, I got the tagName for the OP as well, it should be trivial to figure out how to pass a string.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - exactly, and when you add the slash `<... />` most browsers will remove it if you inspect the DOM in the console, so there's nothing to check for really, other than doing complicated stuff on larger parts of the HTML to see if there's a closing tag somewhere, which isn't really a good solution.

Comment: @adeneo true.. on the other hand, the question itself is trivial, so I have a sneaking suspicion it won't be so trivial for OP

Answer (score 1):

Such an `isSingleClosing` function would look like this:

```js
const isSingleClosing = (tagName, ns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml") => {
    const elem = document?.createElementNS?.(ns, tagName)
        ?? document.createElement(tagName);

    return !(window.XMLSerializer
      ? new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(elem)
      : elem.outerHTML).includes("></");
  };

console.log("Is tag 'img' self-closing?", isSingleClosing("img"));
console.log("Is tag 'p' self-closing?", isSingleClosing("p"));
console.log("Is tag 'bgsound' self-closing?", isSingleClosing("bgsound"));
console.log("Is tag 'image' self-closing?", isSingleClosing("image"));
console.log("Is tag 'image', in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', self-closing?", isSingleClosing("image", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"));
console.log("Is tag 'animateTransform' self-closing?", isSingleClosing("animateTransform"));
console.log("Is tag 'animateTransform', in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', self-closing?", isSingleClosing("animateTransform", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"));
```

It creates the element based on the passed `tagName` and attempts to serialize it. It then tries to find `></` in the serialization. If it’s found, it’s not a self-closing tag, so return `false`, otherwise it is one, so return `true`. This function easily supports [different namespaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS#Important_Namespace_URIs) (e.g. HTML elements, SVG elements, MathML elements, etc.) using `createElementNS`.

At least one of `outerHTML` and `XMLSerializer` is supported in virtually every browser. However, `XMLSerializer` is aware of different namespaces and yields more accurate results. The code above is also written in ECMAScript 2020, which can be transpiled into something more compatible for older browsers, which, in turn, don’t support all of the methods used in the code.

This only covers tags supported in the browser running this function. It will return `true` for `bgsound`, but `false` for `command` or `menuitem` which are deprecated, not standardized, or were never supported by any browser to begin with. `<image>` may have some non-standard or legacy behavior where it’s recognized as a self-closing HTML element.

There’s probably no way to get all cases right in both a backward- and forward-compatible way. But this is better than keeping a long list of elements up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting this question to mean "detect whether an element is [void](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Void_element)"

Self-closing elements—i.e. XHTML—aren't really a thing anymore (JSX looks like XHTML but doesn't generally emit XHTML) and in any event the answer for XHTML is to look at the element's outerHTML for a `/>`).

Especially in these days of custom-elements, it's much harder to answer this question by spouting a list of built-in void elements (you can subclass void elements). I'd suggest:

```
function isVoid(element) {
  element.append('x')
  const isVoid = element.innerText === ''

  // clean up after ourselves
  element.childNodes[element.childNodes.length - 1].remove()
  
  return isVoid
}
```

The reason for this is that void elements support the common properties like `append`, so you can't even assume a void element will have no `children` or `childNodes`.